# oracle 11g SQL :help for a complicated sql query

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I need help...
For example i have this table..

```
acc_num   open  close  activate    date
-------   ----  -----  --------   ----------
 200        1     0        0      2013/01/01
 200        0     1        0      2013/01/12
 200        0     0        1      2013/01/10
```

The output should be:

```
acc_num   open_date   act_date    close_date
 200     2013/01/01   2013/01/10  2013/01/12
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can an account be opened/closed multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (assuming there is only one row per state per acc_num):

```
select acc_num, 
max(decode(open,1,date)) open_date,
max(decode(close,1,date)) close_date,
max(decode(activate,1,date)) activate_date
from table
group by acc_num
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a series of `CASE` statements to create the needed columns.

here is a sample [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e5a88/5)

```
SELECT  t1.acc_num
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN t1.open = 1 THEN t1.date ELSE TO_DATE('1901-01-01', 'YYYY-DD-MM') END) AS Open_Date
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN t1.activate = 1 THEN t1.date ELSE TO_DATE('1901-01-01', 'YYYY-DD-MM') END) AS Activate_Date
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN t1.close = 1 THEN t1.date ELSE TO_DATE('1901-01-01', 'YYYY-DD-MM') END) AS Close_Date
FROM    YourTable t1
GROUP BY
        t1.acc_num
```

Comment: This won't work. A CASE statement requires that all possible "return" values are the same datatype, which your 01/Jan/1901 isn't.

Comment: Added date conversions.

Comment: @Declan_K your date format is not correct and not recognized, it should be `DD/Mon/YYYY`

Comment: now with Oracle recognized date formats and a SQL fiddle demo.

Answer (score 1):

As another approach, as you have tagged your question with `Oracle 11g` tag, you can unpivot your table data and then pivot them back using `UNPIVOT` and `PIVOT` operators  respectively:

```
    select acc_num
         , to_char(open_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd')  as open_date
         , to_char(act_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd')   as act_date
         , to_char(close_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd') as close_date
     from t1
   unpivot(
     val for col in (open1, close1, activate1)
   )
   pivot(
     max(date1) for (col, val) in ( ('OPEN1',1)       as open_date
                                  , ('ACTIVATE1',1)   as act_date
                                  , ('CLOSE1',1)      as close_date
                                  )
   )
```

Result:

```
   ACC_NUM   OPEN_DATE    ACT_DATE     CLOSE_DATE
----------   ----------   ----------   ----------
       200   2013/01/01   2013/01/10   2013/01/12
```

[**SQLFIddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7041d/1)

But using `case` expression would be the easiest way to get the desired result:

```
select acc_num
     , max(case when open1 = 1     then date1 end)  as open_date
     , max(case when activate1 = 1 then date1 end)  as act_date
     , max(case when close1 = 1    then date1 end)  as close_date
  from t1
 group by acc_num
```